# Sorting Range Addresses Numerically

Tags: excel, vba, copy

My code snippet is meant to look through all sheets in workbook and find the address of that specific text's location and copy the region back to a summary page.

***Note: Code below does indeed work for my purposes.***

The summary page algorithm is currently pasting the values as:

> 2,3,1

instead of the desired

> 1,2,3

Currently my FoundRange.Address =

*Pasted from Watch Window*

> "Watch :   :   FoundRange.Address : "$B$60,$B$110,$B$34" : String : Module1.Summarize_POL_Sheets

***Note: `FoundRange` is a variable range that I created within this VBA code***

In order for the get the desired paste order the addresses I would like to be change the address order to "$B$34,$B$60,$B$110"

What would you all recommend would be the best coarse of action to remedy this?
Is there a way to sort this range address by numerical value?

Code snippet shown below:

```
    'Activate current sheet in the sheet loop
    sh.Activate
    
    'Returns a Range object that represents the used range on the specified worksheet
    Set FindRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'finds the last used cell within the active sheet
    Set LastCell = FindRange.Cells(FindRange.Cells.Count)
    'find specified value within our specified cell
    '   Set Find "after" operand to "LastCell",i.e. the last cell used in the active sheet.
    '   The search will “wrap around”; this means it will go back to the start of the range.
    Set FoundCell = FindRange.Find(what:=ReqBlockString, after:=LastCell)
    
    'Test to see if anything was found
      'If FoundCell is something Then
      If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
      Else
        GoTo ReqBlockNotFound
      End If
    
    Set FoundRange = FoundCell
    
      'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
      'Do Loop (1)
      Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        'Find next cell with Text2Find value
         Set FoundCell = FindRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
        
        'Add found cell to FoundRange range variable
         Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, FoundCell)
        
        'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
         If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
          
      Loop
      'End Of Do Loop (1)
      
      '*************Add Sorting Here*******************


     'Copy test for FoundRange
     For Each PasteRange In FoundRange
     
    'FoundRange.Copy
    sh.Range(PasteRange.Address).CurrentRegion.Copy
     
    'Activate the Summary Sheet
    Sheets("Summary").Activate
     
    'Sets copy range to the next available empty row
    Set nextEmptyCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    nextEmptyCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteColumnWidths)
    nextEmptyCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    
    Next PasteRange
```

**UPDATE (Corrected Order)**

Moved the Union statement in-between the Exit condition and the Loop statement
Updated Code shown here:

```
'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
      'Do Loop (1)
      Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        'Find next cell with Text2Find value
         Set FoundCell = FindRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
        
        
        'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
         If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
         
         'Add found cell to FoundRange range variable
         'Moving the Union statement here prevents the First cell from going 
         'through the union statement twice, this was the original culprit
         'for the improper ordering
         Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, FoundCell)
        

      Loop
      'End Of Do Loop (1)
```

Comment: `Find()` should run from the beginning to the end of your search range, so if you move the copy/paste inside the Find loop that should work - you don't need the union'ed range here.

Comment: The order is determined here: `Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, FoundCell)`. To reverse it, well, reverse it: `Set FoundRange = Union(FoundCell, FoundRange)`.

Comment: Thank you guys! I was able to get the order I wanted by moving the Union statement between the Exit condition and Loop statement